# AngularJs ngRepeat series?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have series of objects like this :

```
[[null,"SUPPER",7],[1436306400000,"SUPPER",2],[1436220000000,"SUPPER",1],[null,"DINNER",2],[1436133600000,"BREAKFAST",1],[1436133600000,"SUPPER",2],[null,"BREAKFAST",1],[1436392800000,"DINNER",1]]
```

How can I write each object in table row with ngRepaat?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: you should use `ng-repeat` on `tr` and show data in `td`

Comment: please post what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Fgsrx8VzRfPG7y9seTwQ?p=preview

```
<table border=1>
    <tr ng-repeat="tr in data">
        <td ng-repeat="td in tr">{{ td || '&nbsp;'}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what OP is looking for. ^1

Answer (score 2):

Assign this table to the scope, and then use something similar to this in a template:

```
<!-- Assumes the table you posted is available as "els" on the scope -->
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="e in els">
        <!-- In each table cell, use the first, second and third
             element from the array you have.
             Note: since some of the values are null, I added the
             '|| "empty"] to fallback with some message. -->
        <td>{{ e[0] || "empty" }}</td>
        <td>{{ e[1] || "empty" }}</td>
        <td>{{ e[2] || "empty" }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**DEMO: [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuk0p9oh/)** has a working demo of it, along with the controller.

Comment: how about using forEach?

Comment: @Grundy notice: it's array inside array. So, I'm talking about using forEach rather than e[0], e[1].

Comment: @BhojendraNepal so it more nested `ng-repeat` instead `forEach`, also if in array only third items, so it can be processed manually as in sample

Comment: @Grundy That's what exactly OP is asking for. But unknowingly the question is getting down votes.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, in OP i see only _write each object in table row with ngRepaat_ and in sample - each "object" write with ng-repeat